# UML Relationships

Tags: uml

The Problem is to combine the given UML picture with all possible descriptions.

**UML Diagram**

[image: [1]]

a. It is possible to navigate from B to A.

b. It is possible to navigate from A to B.

c. B only has a weak referece on A.

d. A is a part of B.

e. B is a part of A.

f. There is a unspecific Relation between A and B.

g. When B does not exist anymore, there is no reason for A to exist.

h. When B does not exist anymore, there is still reason for A to exist.

i. B uses A, but has no referece on A.

My Attempts...

Well, I lost the count of how many times I've tried. But it seems to me the descriptions are some what vague. You could say it applies or not...In the end I rearch sth like this...

1. Composition: g,e
2. Aggregation: e,h
3. Line: f,a,b,h
4. Dependency: c,h
5. Association: a,h

And ofc it's still not right...Maybe i was wrong about something I hold for sure. But our tutor clearly didn't provide enough material for us to solve this question and refuse to give any hint. And this is how far I got reading post and article from google...Can someone help to point out what was wrong or missed? I feel I gonna puke...

Comment: What should `Line` be? It's definitely nothing defined in UML. Maybe in Visio.

Comment: I guess that in your picture `Line` should rather be `Association` and `Association` should be `Directed Association`.

Comment: Well, I call it line because i can't find a name for it. All I'm sure about is, it means there is some unspecific relation between 2 components. But does it then means there could alot possibilities such as a and b when it's not specific?

Comment: yea, I guess so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From UML 2.5 perspective:

(¹) I will assume, that the tool used to draw the diagrams doesn't explicitly show association end ownership nor non-navigable ends, so I'll stick to the "common interpretation":

- if no arrows are present, both ends are owned by the respective Classifier, and are navigable
- if only one arrow is present, that direction is owned by the Classifier and is navigable; the other end is owned by the Association and is not navigable

Advanced UML tools can make the distinction explicit by adding black dots to the end or a small cross, to state who owns the association and if it is navigable, respectively.

- A) yes for 4-5, yes for 1-3 (¹)
- B) no for 4-5 (¹), yes for 1-3 (¹)
- C) none based on the information in the diagram alone
- D) none
- E) 1-2
- F) none; 3 is just a regular association and in the context stated earlier doesn't really need anything extra

  - [uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability) calls this unspecified navigability, however that would be only true if the diagramming tool supports (or has not suppressed) all the aforementioned markers (cross, dot)
- G) none; goes hand in hand with D)
- H) all; basically the opposite of G)
- I) all; goes hand in hand with A) for the same reasons

To conclude: I highly recommend to look at the examples in section 11.5.5 of [UML 2.5 specifications](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/).
The whole chapter (11.5) could give you more insight, however it can be quite overwhelming if you've only seen UML as diagrams, and not as models.

---

**Update re: Dependency**

> The presence of Dependency relationships in a model does not have any runtime semantic implications.

I went more thoroughly trough the Specs, here's the Dependency metamodel

[image]

according to this, in dependency neither client, nor supplier know about each other; strictly speaking the model does state that NamedElement (a superclass of Class) knows on whom it depends (clientDependency), however this is defined as follows:

```
{OCL} result = (Dependency.allInstances()->select(d | d.client->includes(self)))
```

On which I call bullshit, because then every non-navigable end could be made navigable with the very same approach.

So, in light of this, for the dependency:

- A) yes by technicality
- B) no by technicality, but nothing really stops me from using the identical approach why A is navigable to also make B navigable

so both A+B are somewhat open to interpretation.

- C) yes and no; depending on interpretation

According to the model it doesn't hold direct reference, however the model also says

> A Dependency implies that the semantics of the clients are not complete without the suppliers.
>   ...
>   A Usage is a Dependency in which one NamedElement **requires** another NamedElement [...] for its full implementation or operation.

So I wouldn't call it a weak reference as the client needs it. In fact UML 2.5 doesn't use the word *weak* once (let alone *weak* reference) in relevant parts of the Spec, so the term itself has no meaning (maybe it was used in old versions of UML).

- I) yes and no, for the very same reasons; the reference is derived (computed from other information), however the Specs also state

> Actions involving a derived Property behave the same as for a nonderived Property.

**Summary:** Dependency is a representation of an idea, not of an implementation; so the actual interpretation is left open to the person using it and to what makes the most sense in a particular context.

I left the original answers as they were, and in this part I more-or-less presented a very mechanical and mindless application of constraints, which is not typically a good idea.

Comment: Yes, thats correct!!! Although "F" is actually on our slide and also in the as a correct answer. We were given just 5 diagramm, I can only upload 1 file, so I use tool to draw them all in 1 picture, so i don't think it has anything to do with the tool. But, yes, everything else is absolutely correct! Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Btw, wiki says"Dependency is a weaker form of bond that indicates that one class depends on another because it uses it at some point in time. " Why doesn't that makes it "a weak referece"? :p

Comment: @ashered I've added more explanation regarding Dependency in more detail than you've ever wanted. :) (Also just because Wikipedia says something doesn't mean it's true... so if in doubt, read the actual UML Specifications ;-) )

Comment: Thanks again for the extra explanation! :)